# Get the file from Azure Blob Storage when it is only updated through C#?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have to get the file Contents from Azure Blob Storage only when it is updated/Created the same file in the Azure Storage. This has to be done through C#.

Comment: `Get the file` from where? Could you please elaborate more, and show us what you have done?

Comment: What do you mean by `only when it is updated/Created the same file in the Azure Storage`? Also, as @Win mentioned, please elaborate more and show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to get the file Contents from Azure Blob Storage only when it is updated/Created the same file in the Azure Storage. This has to be done through C#.

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use azure webjobs or functions blob trigger to get the file content from the blob storage.

The blobtrigger will trigger a process when an Azure blob is created or updated.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to) and below code sample.

```
public static void WriteLog([BlobTrigger("input/{name}")] string logMessage,
        string name,
        string blobTrigger,
        TextWriter logger)
    {
         logger.WriteLine("Full blob path: {0}", blobTrigger);
         logger.WriteLine("Content:");
         logger.WriteLine(logMessage);
    }
```

Notice: The SDK scans log files to watch for new or changed blobs. This process is not real-time; a function might not get triggered until several minutes or longer after the blob is created.

If the speed and reliability limitations of blob triggers are not acceptable for your application, the recommended method is to create a queue message when you create the blob, and use the [QueueTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#trigger) attribute instead of the BlobTrigger attribute on the function that processes the blob.